# Tkinter - Binding Keyboard keys to elements / items on Canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I already know you can bind keys to widgets, or bind Mouse click to elements on a Canvas (eg: rectangle, line, etc), example for the latter:

```py
import tkinter as tk


class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=400, height=400)
        self.canvas.pack()

        # Create the main rectangle
        self.rect = self.canvas.create_rectangle(100, 100, 300, 300, fill="white", outline="black")

        # Create the three small rectangles inside the main rectangle
        self.rect1 = self.canvas.create_rectangle(120, 120, 180, 180, fill="white", outline="black", tags="button1")
        self.rect2 = self.canvas.create_rectangle(220, 120, 280, 180, fill="white", outline="black", tags="button2")
        self.rect3 = self.canvas.create_rectangle(170, 220, 230, 280, fill="white", outline="black", tags="button3")

        # Bind the buttons to the click event and call the hover function
        self.canvas.tag_bind("button1", "<Button-1>", lambda event, tag="button1": self.button_click(event, tag))
        self.canvas.tag_bind("button2", "<Button-1>", lambda event, tag="button2": self.button_click(event, tag))
        self.canvas.tag_bind("button3", "<Button-1>", lambda event, tag="button3": self.button_click(event, tag))

        self.canvas.tag_bind("button1", "<Enter>", lambda event, tag="button1": self.hover(event, tag))
        self.canvas.tag_bind("button2", "<Enter>", lambda event, tag="button2": self.hover(event, tag))
        self.canvas.tag_bind("button3", "<Enter>", lambda event, tag="button3": self.hover(event, tag))

        self.canvas.tag_bind("button1", "<Leave>", lambda event, tag="button1": self.leave(event, tag))
        self.canvas.tag_bind("button2", "<Leave>", lambda event, tag="button2": self.leave(event, tag))
        self.canvas.tag_bind("button3", "<Leave>", lambda event, tag="button3": self.leave(event, tag))

    def button_click(self, event, tag):
        # Get the coordinates of the clicked rectangle
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.canvas.coords(tag)

        # Create a grey rectangle around the clicked rectangle
        self.canvas.delete("clicked")
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1 - 5, y1 - 5, x2 + 5, y2 + 5, outline="grey", fill="grey", tags="clicked")

    def hover(self, event, tag):
        # Get the coordinates of the hovered rectangle
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.canvas.coords(tag)

        # Create a grey rectangle around the hovered rectangle
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1 - 5, y1 - 5, x2 + 5, y2 + 5, outline="grey", tags="hover")

    def leave(self, event, tag):
        # Remove the grey rectangle when the mouse leaves the rectangle
        self.canvas.delete("hover")


root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The above works for binding mouse click to a rectangle. But then I noticed it doesn't actually work if I replace `<Button-1>` with `<KeyPress>` or `<Key>` or specific key, such as `<BackSpace>` for example.

I first thought this wasn't working because of missing focus, so I tried using `canvas.focus_set()` but it only worked if I used it with either `<Enter>` or `<Leave>` when using `canvas.tag_bind`:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=200)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_line(10, 10, 100, 100, tags="mytag")

canvas.create_line(10, 20, 100, 80, tags="mytag")

canvas.create_oval(50, 50, 60, 60, fill="black", tags="mytag")

canvas.create_oval(50, 80, 70, 90, fill="blue", tags="no")



canvas.tag_bind("mytag", "<Enter>", lambda event: print("entered element with mytag"))
canvas.tag_bind("mytag", "<Leave>", lambda event: print("leaving element with mytag"))

root.mainloop()
```

Hovering the mouse on the elements, except for the blue dot, seems to work. The only way I found that worked for binding keys was when using the above with `bind_all`:

```py
def on_keypress(event):
    element_ids = canvas.find_withtag("current")
    if element_ids:
        print("Key pressed over element:", element_ids)

canvas.tag_bind("mytag", "<Enter>", lambda event: canvas.focus_set())
canvas.tag_bind("mytag", "<Leave>", lambda event: root.focus_set())
canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress>", on_keypress)
```

EDIT: It seems like using `canvas.bind` instead of `canvas.bind_all` also work.

But that's not ideal, since I want to bind a single key to a single "group" of elements (eg: they all share the same tag).

Is there any way to do that beside my own non-working attempt?

Comment: What is the point of binding keyboard events to a rectangle in the canvas?

Comment: I wanted to do something similar that what customtkinter does, since it create custom widgets by using elements on a overlaying canvas (eg: rectangle, etc). @acw1668

Comment: You can bind on the canvas instead then.

Comment: But then it wouldn't work if I want to bind different keys to different elements? (I already tried this as you can see on my post above). I wanted to either do this using a class or some way that make it similar to binding against widget (so single group of elements with same tag are seen as a widget, or you can just do groupofelements.bind()) @acw1668

Comment: If binding directly to the canvas and using what I did in my post is truly the only way, I'll post an answer. Otherwise, I'll wait a bit to see if someone more knowledgeable than me in Tkinter maybe have some other way :/

Comment: Does this link will help? https://www.hashbangcode.com/article/using-events-tkinter-canvas-elements-python

Comment: It is helpful, but after reading it all, it seems it only redo part of what I did, using different examples :) The only difference aside from the examples used is that on their blog, they only use mouse's buttons, which already work for binding to element, while keyboard's keys do not work (as noted in my post) @toyotaSupra

Comment: Didn't u scrolled to bottom?

Comment: I did yes (I just finished reading everything) @toyotaSupra

Comment: You can use `tags = canvas.gettags("current")` instead of `element_ids = canvas.find_withtag("current")` to get the *tags* of the item under the cursor.  Then you can do whatever you want if `tags` contains the tag you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binding to `KeyEvent` has the condition of been focused. Focusing the Canvas enables the Canvas for such events. The canvas itself has a completely independent focus that can be given to items that supports the insertion cursor. The only item type that supports the insertion cursor is the `text` item. [This is documented in the section `focus` of the Canvas widget](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/canvas.html#M50) with:

> Set the keyboard focus for the canvas widget to the item given by
> tagOrId. If tagOrId refers to several items, then the focus is set to
> the first such item in the display list that supports the insertion
> cursor. If tagOrId does not refer to any items, or **if none of them
> support the insertion cursor, then the focus is not changed.** If
> tagOrId is an empty string, then the focus item is reset so that no
> item has the focus. If tagOrId is not specified then the command
> returns the id for the item that currently has the focus, or an empty
> string if no item has the focus.
>
> **Once the focus has been set to an item, the item will display the
> insertion cursor and all keyboard events will be directed to that
> item.** The focus item within a canvas and the focus window on the
> screen (set with the focus command) are totally independent: **a given
> item does not actually have the input focus unless (a) its canvas is
> the focus window and (b) the item is the focus item within the canvas.**
> In most cases it is advisable to follow the focus widget command with
> the focus command to set the focus window to the canvas (if it was not
> there already).

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=200)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_line(10, 10, 100, 100, tags="mytag")
canvas.create_line(10, 20, 100, 80, tags="mytag")
canvas.create_oval(50, 50, 60, 60, fill="black", tags="mytag")
canvas.create_oval(50, 80, 70, 90, fill="blue", tags="no")
canvas.create_text(100,100, text='hello', tags="mytag")

def on_keypress(event):
    canvas.focus_set()
    element_ids = canvas.find_withtag("current")
    canvas.focus(element_ids)
    if element_ids:
        print("Key pressed over element:", element_ids)

canvas.tag_bind("mytag", "<Enter>", on_keypress)
canvas.tag_bind("mytag", "<Leave>", lambda event: root.focus_set())
canvas.tag_bind("mytag", "<KeyPress>", lambda e:print(e))

root.mainloop()
```